# How could i flip content of a binary file with bash commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, binary

I was wondering if it's possible to do bitwise conversion on a binary file, with bash commands, (in my case bitwise negation).

Comment: What's a _bash command_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
LC_ALL=C tr '\0-\377' '\377\376\375\374\373\372\371\370\367\366\365\364\363\362\361\360\357\356\355\354\353\352\351\350\347\346\345\344\343\342\341\340\337\336\335\334\333\332\331\330\327\326\325\324\323\322\321\320\317\316\315\314\313\312\311\310\307\306\305\304\303\302\301\300\277\276\275\274\273\272\271\270\267\266\265\264\263\262\261\260\257\256\255\254\253\252\251\250\247\246\245\244\243\242\241\240\237\236\235\234\233\232\231\230\227\226\225\224\223\222\221\220\217\216\215\214\213\212\211\210\207\206\205\204\203\202\201\200\177\176\175\174\173\172\171\170\167\166\165\164\163\162\161\160\157\156\155\154\153\152\151\150\147\146\145\144\143\142\141\140\137\136\135\134\133\132\131\130\127\126\125\124\123\122\121\120\117\116\115\114\113\112\111\110\107\106\105\104\103\102\101\100\77\76\75\74\73\72\71\70\67\66\65\64\63\62\61\60\57\56\55\54\53\52\51\50\47\46\45\44\43\42\41\40\37\36\35\34\33\32\31\30\27\26\25\24\23\22\21\20\17\16\15\14\13\12\11\10\7\6\5\4\3\2\1\0' < file.in > file.out
```

Or:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1} $_ = pack("C", unpack("C", $_) ^ 0xff)' < file.in > file.out
```

Comment: And you can generate that ridiculously long parameter to `tr` with `$(echo '\'$(seq 399 -1 0 | grep -v "[89]") | sed 's/ /\\/g')`.

Comment: @G-Man, more like `"$(printf '\\%o' {255..0})"` with zsh/bash/ksh93. Though, since it's always the same, there's no good reason you'd want to generate it every time.